# Expression not working in the OBIEE filter

Tags: obiee

```
Date <= CASE WHEN UPPER(DAYNAME(@{CMA}{date '2017-09-05'})) = 'SAT'
             THEN TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY,2, (@{CMA}{date '2017-09-05'}))
        ELSE (@{CMA}{date '2017-09-05})
        END
```

I'm using the expression in the filter as an SQL Expression. When I go to edit the report through catalog am getting data in the results tab. But when I run the report through dashboard it throws error because of this filter. Is there anything wrong with the expression?

Answer (score 0):

That means that the dashboard must be filling the variable wrong. When you run the analysis (not "report") from the catalog is runs precisely as configured. In a dashboard context you have to watch out what the prompts fill the variable with.